# Do I need to include an info icon on my links that fire a lightbox?

Tags: icons, checkout

I'm building a multi-step checkout process and I have a bunch of links within each step that provide additional information for the user about specific input fields. The input field/and links are spaced about 60px apart (horizontally). Each link has a round "i" info icon in front. I'm wondering if the info icon is even needed on these links? or if I can get away with just the text and remove the (i) icon altogether to clean up the layout.

The only reason I've hesitated to remove the (i) icon is because it could make the links feel like they are just floating, but then again what does having the icon even add to the overall user experience?

Thoughts?

Comment: This is kind of a visual design question, possibly a better fit for GraphicDesign.SE. It's also a bit difficult to answer without an image. From a UX perspective, you only need the icon if the user needs that additional context.

Comment: Can you please post an image? So that it will be easy for others to reply

Comment: @plainclothes In my opinion this question is about the ux not the design

Answer (score 2):

Affordance and Signifiers. Don Norman writes about these in his book The Design of Everyday Things

You should ask yourself:

1. Are the links clickable? (Affordance)
2. If yes, are the links recognizable as clickable? (Signifier)
3. Do the links here work as any other links on your website? That is, while other links take you to a different page, does this one do something different: open a lightbox?
4. How important do you think it is to visually communicate that this link works differently than others?

I don't have to stress the importance of the check-out process. Provide all the information that will aid in the checkout process. Prevent your users from confusion and uncertainty: the uncertainty that clicking on a certain link, for more information, might open up a new page, and all entries she made might be lost. (Even though if in reality all entries would be saved, the mental stress is unnecessary and would result in a bad experience)

Having a pretty interface and high dropout rate is worse than having an okay interface with higher conversion. That said, everybody love pretty interface so find a design solution that has the best of both worlds.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer @stringtheory! This is a fantastic bit of feedback and has definitely pointed me in the right direction. I'll pickup Don Normans book and give it a read. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. Good luck on your project (: